# Browsers ignoring CSS?

Tags: safari, fonts, firefox, css

I have this in a CSS file:

```
p {
    margin: 50;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

On MacOS, Safari honored the margin but ignored font-family and font-size.  I tried it in Firefox, and the font-family and margin were honored.  Changed "50" to "150" in both places, and in both browsers opened the CSS file itself (i.e., made the browser display the actual contents) and clicked refresh.  Saw the contents change.  Went to the HTML page and clicked refresh.  Neither side changed.

Closed both browsers, moved both CSS and HTML to a different URI.  Opened Safari and removed all cache and cookies.  Opened Firefox and pointed both browsers to the new location.  No change in font-family, margin, or font-size.

There is no inline style in the HTML.  There are no other mentions of these three attributes in the CSS.

**Is there something wrong with my CSS syntax?**

(Tried to put this on superuser SE but the captcha is broken.)

Comment: This might be a better question for Stack Overflow (https://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: you missed the unit in case of margin, it should be 50px, or I will recommend you to use rem unit by converting px into rem, I use http://pxl2rem.com/px-to-rem myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Units? I assume you want px.

```
p {
    margin: 50px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

em, ex, %, px, cm, mm, in, pt, pc, ch, rem, vh, vw, ect are possible units.

Inline style would be, (but please don't):

```
<p style="margin: 50px;">...</p>
```

For readability (and for the love of humanity) of the document (using inline style means the person looking at the code if they need to change it will spend a lot of time figuring it out), inline style should almost never be used.

On margins there are collapsible margins that sometimes or under some circumstances don't. I pity anybody trying to debug margins with them being set via inline style.

Comment: I'll have to test of course, but I'm fairly certain you've spotted my mistake.

Comment: +1 for inline comments.  Drove me nuts on a web team when we were required to use an HTML generator.  When it failed (often!) having to debug HTML with no line breaks, tons of inline style tags, font change elements opened and closed with no content between, tables used for some of the formatting, etc. …